# Add Initial basic feasible solution for simplex using GLPK

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I'd like to know if it is possible to introduce an initial basic feasible solution to the simplex in glpk, this in order to avoid de initialization phase of the algorithm and save computation time. I also want to know if glpk library uses the standard simplex or the revised simplex. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set a custom basis by using 
*glp_set_col_stat()*. You will have to set each column to be Basic (GLP_BS) or Non-basic (GLP_NL). You could also use the API *glp_adv_basis* method, though I don't think it lets you customize the basis.

I recommend the very readable Section 2.6 in the [LP Basis Construction Routines here](https://www.cs.unb.ca/~bremner/docs/glpk/glpk.pdf).

And yes, GLPK uses the Revised Simplex. I believe this is the default setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very useful. I'm trying to design a digital filter using linear programming techniques. In order to do that I need to solve the dual problem wich has less constraints than variables (about 100 constraints by 5000 variables). So I wonder if glpk decide by itself to solve the dual instead the primal or I have to introduce the dual in the begining. My goal is to save computation time and resources.  I hope you can help me

Comment: @RobertoTalaveraDieguez Yes, most modern solvers will right away figure out if it is much better to solve the dual instead of the primal problem. Esp. true in cases where one dimension is much greater than the other.